# Is chronological order of logging messages guaranteed?

Tags: python, logging, supervisord

I'm using the `logging` module to log messages from an application server. More specifically, I use a StreamHandler to log messages to stdout/stderr, and use `Supervisord` to log those messages to files (since the server process is monitored by `Supervisord`).

My main question is, does the order of messages in the log file **always truthfully** reflect the order of execution of the code? For example, if a message `A: this is log msg A` appears before message `B: this is log msg B` in a log file, then can we be 100% certain that the line of code that logs message `A` was executed before the line of the code that logs message `B`, even if the timestamps of the two messages in the log file are the same?

Comment: Are you running a single thread? Then yes, log entries will be entered into the file in the order the code emitted it. With threading, locking comes into play and the thread that has the lock first wins. Even then, log messages from the same thread will never be written out in a different order, they'll just be intermixed with messages from other threads.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! useful info. Do you know of any module/tool that makes sure messages are chronologically arranged?

Comment: @AmitTripathi: define 'chronologically'. If two threads log *at the same time* then the first to get the lock gets to log first. The entries are then still entered chronologically (the thread that lost the lock toss has to wait a brief moment before it successfully completes the logging).

Answer (score 4):

You can't be be 100% sure, I'm pretty sure.

Although the logging module locks the output file before writing to it, if you're running multiple threads or processes there's no guarantee that your code that called `logging.warning("A")` or whatever actually acquires the lock if several other threads are trying to do the same at around the same time.

See also the [docs for logging](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/logging.html#thread-safety) and also [its source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f7b552020d44/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l194). We see that it uses `threading.RLock`, about which [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html#threading.RLock.acquire) say:

> If more than one thread is blocked waiting until the lock is unlocked,
>   only one at a time will be able to grab ownership of the lock. There
>   is no return value in this case.

We can't be entirely certain of which thread gets the lock first, which is the problem.